# Making an image slide out from side of the page and then stop

Tags: css

I'm looking to animate three images. I basically want them to do what the image in this link does - http://dabblet.com/gist/3834617 - but instead of stopping and then sliding off of the page, I just want it to slide in and stop in the middle.

The first one will slide in from the left, the second will slide in underneath from the right, and the last will slide in under the other two from the left.

I've been trying to play around with the numbers in the keyframe code, but no luck. Any help would be awesome. Thanks :)

```
<div id"image"><img src="images/fffff.jpg" width="2000" height="352" /></div> 

img { 
position: absolute; 
left: -100%; 
margin: 7em -244px; 
animation: slide 10s infinite; } 

@keyframes slide { 
0% { left: 0%; }
35% { left: 50%; }
85% { left: 50%; }
100% { left: 50%; }
```

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted in your post. Without it, we can't help you much.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I just gave the link because that's all I really need, but here is what I have.

Just added it to the OP

Answer (score 0):

### One image

[**Demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/9279639)

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 7em -244px;
    animation: slide 4s 1;
}
@keyframes slide {
    from { left: -150%; }
    to { left: 50%; }
}
```

### Three images

[**Demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/9279789)

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 7em -244px;
    top: 0;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
#img1{ animation-name: slideTop; }
#img2{ animation-name: slideLeft; }
#img3{ animation-name: slideRight; }
@keyframes slideRight {
    from { left: -150%; }
    to { left: 50%; }
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
    from { left: 200%; }
    to { left: 50%; }
}
@keyframes slideTop {
    from { top: 200%; }
    to { top: 0%; }
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Now for the one coming in on right, how would I apply this to that image? I assume I would change "left" to "right," but applying it to image 2... ?

Comment: @KelseyKronmiller Doesn't it work now? You could use `right` if you want, but I prefer using `left` too in order to avoid a mess of `left` and `right` mixed.

Comment: You rock hahaha. Got it to work the way I want. Thank you very much :) Trying to upvote you but I'm not a high enough "level" D: